# Why is php.ini file not updating (open_basedir) when I restart apache on phpinfo page?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I made a change to my [open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) value, and then I restarted Apache but when I go to view my phpinfo page it still shows the old value; why is this not being updated?

Comment: Are you updating the same php.ini that's listed in your phpinfo?

Comment: Yes, I see the "Local Value" is showing what was entered before I updated it, but the new change isn't showing up.  Is there any cache that could be causing the value not show updated?

Comment: Do you have a control panel of some sort? Like Plesk, cpanel, etc?

Comment: Yes, Plesk but I checked "PHP Settings" and it's set to "Use Default" values.

Comment: I restarted "Apache" and "PHP-FPM" in Plesk and the changes still don't take effect...strange.

Comment: Have you checked that `open_basedir` is not being set somewhere else? It can be set in the Apache server config, `.user.ini` files etc.

Comment: Finally figured it out, this open_basedir was being controlled by Plesk; so I just had to update this value in Plesk under "PHP Settings" page.